# filter all two tables to get all the data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures

I created a database for survey software. The two tables of the database are what I want to do, I want to get the average scores from the two date ranges and from a place, and get the ones without the answer as null or 0. I tried

```
SELECT
    AVG(tbAnswers.averageScore)
FROM
    tbDrivers
LEFT JOIN tbAnswers ON tbDrivers.driverId = tbAnswers.driverId
WHERE
    tbDrivers.place = 'WDC'
GROUP BY
    tbDrivers.driverId
```

But when I specify the date range, is not get the data of the drivers without answer.

```
SELECT AVG(tbAnswers.averageScore)
FROM tbDrivers LEFT JOIN tbAnswers ON tbDrivers.driverId = tbAnswers.driverId
WHERE tbDrivers.place = 'WDC'
      AND answerDate BETWEEN '2018-11-28' AND '2018-12-03'
GROUP BY tbDrivers.driverId
```

Table structures:
[image: structure]

```
CREATE TABLE `tbAnswers` (
  `answerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answerDate` date NOT NULL,
  `driverId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `averageScore` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbAnswers` (`answerId`, `answerDate`, `driverId`, `score1`, `score2`, `score3`, `averageScore`) VALUES
(10, '2018-11-28', 1032, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(11, '2018-11-29', 1032, 9, 8, 3, 6.67),
(12, '2018-11-30', 1032, 0, 3, 2, 1.67),
(13, '2018-11-30', 1035, 10, 2, 10, 7.34),
(14, '2018-11-01', 1032, 5, 5, 5, 5),
(15, '2018-12-03', 1035, 5, 5, 7, 5.67);

CREATE TABLE `tbDrivers` (
  `driverId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nameSurname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `place` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `plate` varchar(8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbDrivers` (`driverId`, `nameSurname`, `place`, `plate`) VALUES
(1032, 'Nick Oliver', 'WDC', 'B16186D'),
(1033, 'Nicholas Keller', 'WDC', 'ACG8095'),
(1034, 'Felipe Mendez', 'WDC', 'C26106E'),
(1035, 'Lowell Butler', 'WDC', '5123QK');
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: where is the query for date in where condition?

Comment: @KedarLimaye 
i tried:
`SELECT
    AVG(tbAnswers.averageScore)
FROM
    tbDrivers
LEFT JOIN tbAnswers ON tbDrivers.driverId = tbAnswers.driverId
WHERE
    tbDrivers.place = 'WDC' AND answerDate BETWEEN '2018-11-28' AND '2018-12-03'
GROUP BY
    tbDrivers.driverId` I can't get values ​​that are "null" when I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you have no records for driverid in tbanswers table.

Either make an entry in tbanswers or Use Query given by Forpas above or use this query

```
SELECT tbdrivers.driverid, 
       Avg(tbanswers.averagescore) 
FROM   tbdrivers 
       LEFT JOIN tbanswers 
              ON tbdrivers.driverid = tbanswers.driverid 
WHERE  tbdrivers.place = 'WDC' 
       AND answerdate BETWEEN '2018-11-28' AND '2018-12-03' 
        OR answerdate IS NULL 
GROUP  BY tbdrivers.driverid
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your query which fetches the drivers that have at least 1 answer, `UNION` the drivers that have no answer:

```
(SELECT tbDrivers.driverId, AVG(tbAnswers.averageScore) AS avgscore
FROM tbDrivers LEFT JOIN tbAnswers ON tbDrivers.driverId = tbAnswers.driverId
WHERE tbDrivers.place = 'WDC'
      AND answerDate BETWEEN '2018-11-28' AND '2018-12-03'
GROUP BY tbDrivers.driverId )
UNION 
(SELECT t.driverId,  NULL AS avgscore
FROM tbDrivers t
WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbAnswers WHERE tbAnswers.driverId = t.driverId))
ORDER BY driverId
```

the result is:

```
driverId    avgscore
1032        2.7800000111262
1033        (null)
1034        (null)
1035        6.505000114440918
```